# Não exibir mais uma linha na tabela quando status for igual a "Cancelado"

Tags: java, primefaces, java-ee

Tenho uma `<p:dataTable>` que é preenchida por dados que estão em um arquivo `.xml` e tenho na frente de cada linha um botão para finalizar ou cancelar o processo. Como eu faço pra não exibir mais em minha `DataTable` o processo que foi cancelado. Tem como excluir todas as tags relacionadas a coluna do arquivo `xml`? ou seria mais simples toda vez que eu clicar em cancelar ele mudaria o status no arquivo `.xml` para cancelado dessa forma eu poderia fazer uma condição para não exibi-lo. Alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que tratar os dados que serão exibidos na tabelas antes de envia-los. O datatable não tem suporte para esconder linhas.